# When I do an update on ubuntu "sudo apt update" appears like this what is the solution.?

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, update-manager, error-handling

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1165 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:25 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list:49
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list:49
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list:49
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list:49
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list:49
```

Comment: The first error is caused by your attempting to run updates in more than one job simultaneously. Only one job can run updates at a time, so it locks out other attempts.